# Proof involving the span of vectors in $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

Hi I'm having trouble with this question on my homework sheet:

Let $v_1
, .\ldots, v_k$ be arbitrary vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

(a) Prove that if $V$ is any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$
containing $v_1
, .\ldots, v_k$
then span$\{v_1
,\ldots , v_k\} \subset V$."

So I know that something is a subspace if and only if its non empty i.e doesn't contain the empty set, is closed under vector addition and closed under scalar multiplication. I also know that a span gives you all the vectors you need to make all other vectors in that space i.e. any vector $S$ in that space can be made from $c_{1}v_{1}+\cdots+c_{k}v_{k}$.

Comment: Given $x=c_{1}v_{1}+\ldots c_{k}v_{k}\in span\{v_{1},\ldots v_{k}\}$, since $v_{1},\ldots v_{k}\in V$ and $V$ is a subspace, then $x\in V$.

Comment: @Xammm How do you go from "since $v_1$,…$v_k$ ∈ V and V is a subspace" to "x ∈ V"

Comment: Is it due to scalar multiplication and vector addition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element in span$\{v_{1},\ldots,v_{k}\}$ looks like
$$
c_{1}v_{1}+\cdots+c_{k}v_{k}, 
$$
where $c_{1},\ldots,c_{k}\in\mathbb{R}$. Since $V$ is a subspace, it is closed under scalar multiplication. So, since $V$ contains each $v_{i}$, it also contains $c_{i}v_{i}$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. But, being a subspace, $V$ is also closed under vector addiction. So, $c_{1}v_{1}+\cdots+c_{k}v_{k}\in V$. It follows that span$\{v_{1},\ldots,v_{k}\}\subset V$.